# JMSSerializerBundle: "exclusion_policy: NONE" doesn't work

Tags: php, json, rest, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-2.8

Currently I'm developing a RESTful API application with Symfony 2.8, FOSUserBundle and JMSSerializerBundle.

I have a controller action that displays a list of categories available to be attached to advertisements. Categories are represented by `AppBundle:Category` entity.

Here's the **controller** code:

```
class CategoryController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @DI\Inject("app.category_repository")
     * 
     * @var CategoryRepository
     */
    private $categoryRepository;

    public function getCategoriesAction()
    {   
        $countries = $this->categoryRepository->findAll();

        $context = new Context();
        $context->addGroups(["category-list"]);

        $view = $this->view($countries, 200);
        $view->setContext($context);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Here's my **Category entity** code:

```php
/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

**JMSSerializerBundle** configuration:

```yml
jms_serializer:
    property_naming:
        separator:  _
        lower_case: true

    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        cache: file
        debug: "%kernel.debug%"
        file_cache:
            dir: "%kernel.cache_dir%/serializer"
        directories:
            AppBundle:
                namespace_prefix: AppBundle
                path: %kernel.root_dir%/config/serializer/AppBundle
```

Here's my **Category entity** configuration:

```yml
AppBundle\Entity\Category:
    exclusion_policy: NONE
```

What I expect to get when I call the API:

```json
{"0":{"id":1,"name":"category1"},"1":{"id":2,"name":"category2"}}
```

What I actually get:

```json
{"0":{},"1":{}}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

***UPDATE***

If I'm setting the configuration like this:

```php
AppBundle\Entity\Category:
    exclusion_policy: ALL    
    properties:
        id:
            groups: ["category-list", "category-entity"]
        name:
            groups: ["category-list", "category-entity"]
```

then I get the following response:

```json
[{"id":1,"name":"category1"},{"id":2,"name":"category2"}]
```

***UPDATE 2***
If I change my controller action, that is, comment all the lines setting the serialization context and switch `exclusion_policy` into `NONE` the API works correctly:

```php
public function getCategoriesAction()
{   
    $categories = $this->categoryRepository->findAll();

    //$context = new Context();
    //$context->addGroups(["category-list"]);

    $view = $this->view($categories, 200);
    //$view->setContext($context);

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

```yml
AppBundle\Entity\Category:
    exclusion_policy: NONE
```

It brings me the following output:

```json
[{"id":1,"name":"category1"},{"id":2,"name":"category2"}]
```

Comment: I think this have nothing to do with exclusion_policy because according to [doc](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) 'The default exclusion policy is to exclude nothing.' Maybe I miss it, but I don't see you serialize your data... You should take a look JMS usage : http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer#usage

Comment: @mickdev As I far as I understand, $this->handleView() method does the serialization work as well. If I change the configuration (see the question update), the API works properly.

Comment: ok, so everything is fine then. Anyway, I prefer annotations on entity declaration, it's more readable imo. something like this : http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies

Comment: @mickdev The issue is that I want Category entity to be serialized like in the last example not only for CategoryController but also for other controllers and it's quite painful to copy and paste a long list of groups from one yaml file to another...

Comment: I don't get it. You have to define the configuration only once, right ? I'm not really familiar with YML but if you have to reproduce the same configuration in all your bundles, you'd better use annotation directly on entity declaration file. You can also define the configuration in `app/config/config.yml` so it will be application wide

Comment: @mickdev I mean that if, for example, I need to serialize all the fields of Category while showing the list of adverts, I have to go to yml config file for Advert entity (or to the Advert entity file to copy the annotation, there's no difference) and paste "advert-list", "advert-entity" groups into the Category config file. But if there's some other group that needs Category to be serialized, I have not to forget to add this group into Category config. For me it's a bit unpleasant.  I think there should be some way to make Category fully serialized if some entity has it as association...

Comment: @mickdev please look at the update 2.